# jQuery Gallery is not working in WordPress

Tags: css

Even though, I used same code for both of them http://bda.ctuproject.com/ is not showing tip image. When you go over any item in http://bda.ctuproject.com/wp-content/themes/twentyten/exam/index.html you will see that box will come up saying what is that picture but it's not doing it when I put it in WordPress. Why any ideas ?

1. http://bda.ctuproject.com
2. http://bda.ctuproject.com/wp-content/themes/twentyten/exam/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you're calling the jquery script twice

Comment: nope only once; 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/twentyten/carousel/image-slideshow.js"></script>

Comment: Meant the library: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   and <script type='text/javascript' src='http://bda.ctuproject.com/wp-content/plugins/sponsors-carousel/jquery-1.4.2.min.js?ver=1.4.2'></script>

Comment: You can just solely use this <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js this takes latest jquery so I dont have to deal with changing code in the future.

Comment: Good point, but you did have a nice 1.4.2 version loading :P - my thoughts though would be using google's linkage would be a tad bit speedier and stable... whether or not that is true, it's probably not enough that one would notice anyways

Comment: http://www.impressivewebs.com/linking-to-jquery/ -> Good points to support my last comment, first comment on there gives an extra reason

Answer (score 0):

As @Colby said, you are loading jQuery twice. Try putting this into your active theme's functions.php file to deregister the WP jQuery load:

```
if( !is_admin()){
  wp_deregister_script('jquery');
}
```